Property co-occurrence constraints in TypeScript results in `never` when combining
I have two types (extending a common base type) I want to combine, such that when one of the properties exclusive to a subtype is present, all properties exclusive to it are known to be present (i.e., TypeScript and ESLint can recognize it to be that subtype).
I have found very similar situations in TypeScript: Optional merge types and Can Typescript Interfaces express co-occurrence constraints for properties; however, attempts to implement their solutions result in never being inferred by the ESLint linter.
I am using ESLint in VS Code for my TS typechecking, and it is raising the errors mentioned.
For example, here I have types ConfigA and ConfigB that both extend BaseConfig.
interface BaseConfig {
  fooB: boolean;
  optbar?: number;
}

interface ConfigA extends BaseConfig {
  fooB: false;
  first: number;
}

interface ConfigB extends BaseConfig {
  fooB: true;
  second: number;
  third: number;
}

I wish to combine them in a type like AnyConfig:
type AnyConfig = /* ... either ConfigA or ConfigB are allowable ... */;

Expected inference behavior:
variable assignments
const cfgA: ConfigA = {   // good
  fooB: false,
  first: 1
};

const cfgB: ConfigB = {   // good
  fooB: true,
  optbar: 42,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
};

const cfgBadHasBoth: ConfigA = {        // fails
  fooB: false,
  first: 1,
  third: 3
};

const cfgBadMissingParam: ConfigB = {   // fails
  fooB: true,
  second: 2
}

const cfgBadFoo: ConfigA = {            // fails
  fooB: true,
  first: 1
}


AnyConfig variable assignment
let someCfg: AnyConfig;

// either should be assignable to it

someCfg = cfgA;  // should be ok
someCfg = cfgB;  // should be ok


ESLint should infer which are present when faced with conditions like:

if (typeof someCfg.first !== "undefined") {
  // someCfg must be ConfigA

  let a: number = someCfg.first;   // should be ok
  let b: number = someCfg.second;  // should raise type error

  let c: number | undefined = someCfg.optbar;  // should be ok
  let d: number = someCfg.optbar ?? 70;        // should be ok
  let e: number = someCfg.optbar;              // should raise type error
}

if (someCfg.fooB) {
  // someCfg must be ConfigB

  let a: number = someCfg.first;   // should raise type error
  let b: number = someCfg.second;  // should be ok

  ...
}


Actual behavior:
ESLint says 'AnyConfig' is inferred to be never:
following TypeScript: Optional merge types:
type None<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: never}
type EitherOrBoth<T1, T2> = T1 & None<T2> | T2 & None<T1> | T1 & T2

// problem: eslint thinks "type AnyConfig = never"
type AnyConfig = EitherOrBoth<ConfigA, ConfigB>;

trying to be explicit by expanding instead of subtyping, opposing DRY:
// expanded definitions
interface ConfigA {
  fooB: false;
  optbar?: number;
  first: number;
}

interface ConfigB {
  fooB: true;
  optbar?: number;
  second: number;
  third: number;
}

// problem: eslint thinks "type AnyConfig = never"
type AnyConfig = EitherOrBoth<ConfigA, ConfigB>;

Attempting the AnyConfig variable assignment
ESLint should recognize the type ConfigA is allowable, but instead it produces the error "Type 'ConfigA' is not assignable to type 'never'":
let someCfg: AnyConfig = cfgA;  // fails, "not assignable to type 'never'"

How can I define AnyConfig such that let someCfg: AnyConfig = cfgA; works as expected, inference and all?

• You are mentioning eslint but not describing whether your information is coming from eslint or typescript. Please check and then [edit] to remove references to eslint if it's not directly involved here. • Why would cfgBadFoo fail? Looks fine to me and to my IDE. • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz 1) I am using ESLint in VSCode, and it is showing these errors. I've edited to try to clarify that.
2) Thank you, that was a mistake, I meant to exemplify cfgBadFoo should fail for ConfigA and fooB: true -- not false. For ConfigA fooB should be literally false, and vice versa. I fixed that example in the question.
3) Thank you for your approach, yes it is meeting my needs! If you wish to write it as an answer I will accept it.

• But ESLint isn't showing that error, that's a TypeScript error. Just because you're using ESLint it doesn't mean that's what's producing the error you describe. It's as if you said (assuming you're using a PC) Windows produced the error because you're using Windows. ESLint does sometimes show errors (and so does Windows) but you need to check that's what's producing them or else it's a red herring.

Good point. Well, the project I am writing is using Vite which is using tsup for compiling. It does not fail to build my code, even with those aforementioned linting errors. ...Obviously the linter is to keep the typing in check as I code. It does make me question, should I find a way to force tsup to follow the eslint rules...

Update: upon further research it appears tsup does not check for errors when compiling. I ran tsc --noEmit and tsc will throw errors like eslint shows.
